# Lograr que un botón que al presionarse cambia un texto, cambie el texto al original al presionarlo de nuevo

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones, botón

He creado un botón que al presionarse cambia un texto, me gustaría lograr que al presionarlo de nuevo, el texto cambiase al  que estaba al principio, y así sucesivamente.

He intentado con esto, pero me sale [object HTMLParagraphElement]

```js
var texto1 = document.getElementById('texto')
var texto2 = "adios";
function cambiartexto() {
    texto.innerHTML = texto2;
    if (texto.innerHTML == texto2) {
        texto.innerHTML = texto1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="texto">hola</p>
        <button onclick="cambiartexto()">Presiona aquí</button>
        <script src="/JS/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que haces mal el `if`, pues haces `texto.innerHTML == texto2` donde comparas la propiedad `innerHtML`, otra cosa donde tienes la variable `texto`?, creo que te puedes referir a `texto1` para poder cambiar el valor del elemento.

Para poder cambiar el texto al presionar el botón, vamos a hacer una especie de *toggle*, para eso definimos una variable, llamada `cambio` la cual estará en `false` cuando el texto sea original y `true` cuando tenga otro valor.

```js
var texto = document.getElementById('texto')
var palabra = "hola";//definimos el texto original
var texto2 = "adios";
var cambio = false
function cambiartexto() {
    if (cambio) {
        texto.innerHTML = palabra;
        cambio = false
    }else{
      texto.innerHTML = texto2;
      cambio = true
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="texto">hola</p>
        <button onclick="cambiartexto()">Presiona aquí</button>
        <script src="/JS/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

teniendo en tu HTML esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="texto">hola</p>
        <button onclick="cambiartexto()">Presiona aquí</button>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Podes resumir tu función cambiar texto, de esta forma:

```
cambiartexto = () => {
    texto = document.getElementById('texto')
    texto.innerHTML = texto.innerHTML  == "texto 1"?"texto 2":"texto 1"
}
```

Tené en cuenta, que esto no tomara el texto inicial de tu HTML, si queres que eso suceda, podes agregar esto:

```
let texto_original = ""
cambiartexto = () => {
    let texto = document.getElementById('texto')
    
    texto_original = texto_original==""?texto.innerHTML:texto_original
    
    texto.innerHTML = texto.innerHTML  == texto_original?"texto 2":texto_original
}
```